# SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' - Cypress, TypeScript and Axios

Tags: typescript, axios, cypress

I'm trying to create simple API test with Axios, but getting below error:
How to solve below problem?

```
SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

My test file

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
  });
```

Basic setting of my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
      "types": ["cypress", "node"],
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
  }
```

I add below dependencies in my package.json

```
{
  "main": "index.ts",
  "sourceType": "module",
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/browserify": "^12.0.37",
    "@types/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.0.1",
    "axios": "^1.2.0",
    "cypress": "^9.7.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "tsc": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^8.8.0",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.15.5",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what file this happens in?

Comment: const axios = require('axios');

  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
  });

Comment: Please edit your initial question to include that, instead of having it as a comment.

Comment: this error is in cypress log:

Comment: ok, sure. I will add it. Do you know why it's failing with such error?

Comment: `"sourceType": "module",` should just be `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`. Note that node.js generally won't run modules without the .mjs file extension.

Comment: many thanks for your reply. Unfortunately  "type": "module" not helps. Any other ideas?

Comment: Somebody has some ideas, please?

Comment: There's no use of `import/export` in the code you posted?

Comment: No, I’m using:  const axios = require('axios');